# Automate Apex Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

I have written Test classes for my APEX Classes.
I want to automate these Test suite to be run daily at 8:00 AM for an example. 
How can I achieve that?
Can I use schedulable apex class where I call all the test classes to run it and schedule at my preferred time or do I need a crone job kind of thing to schedule at?

I would appreciate any kind of idea or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement the `schedulable` interface with `@isTest` class and it works fine with test class so you can use that with cron expression.

But, I don't think it will work as expected because test class is not considered in apex code limit. The other point is if you implement `schedulable` with test class then again you have to write the test class for the test class and it will go into a loop.

So, I don't think you can run test class at a particular time.

You can go with this link also for the implementation.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HlPT

Comment: Thanks @Ram. Even I thought of the same as I will write test class for the schedulable class. Let me check in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

In a project we've used [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) to schedule tests. It can send you an email with the results and the % of test coverage. 
It can do a whole range of other stuff too, but the free version at least supports test scheduling.

[Here's a Youtube video they made explaining how it works](https://youtu.be/V9QB2k1PQlA)

PS. I don't work for Gearset

Comment: Thanks. Let me try with that. Though I have used gearset but for different purpose.

Comment: @Sagar What did you think of it? Does it solve your use case?

Comment: I created one schedulable class and create an automation which runs all the test class and send email to all the devs with Pass/fail per class and per method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up sfdx for your organization, and use the `force:apex:test:run` command to get your code coverage at any given time. The tricky part would be writing a script to run on your system at a given time, plus figuring out how to report the coverage.

You can read more about sfdx [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli).

> What is it?
>
> The Salesforce DX CLI is a powerful command line interface that simplifies development and build automation when working with your Salesforce org. Use it to:
>
> - Aggregate all the tools you need to develop with and perform commands against your Salesforce org
> - Synchronize source to and from scratch orgs
> - Create and manage orgs
> - Import and export data
> - Create and execute tests
> - Create and install packages

You can learn more about setting up sfdx [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sfdx_setup.pdf).

---

Once set up, running this command will return your org's code coverage:

```
$ sfdx force:apex:test:run -c
```

You can learn more about running tasks daily here:

1. MacOS: [How can I get a script to run everyday?](https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x)
2. Windows: [MSDN: SCheduling Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @battery.cord.. I was not aware of sfdx. interesting thing to learn.